# TFS 10 Files 11 Different Comments

Tags: tfs, comments, checkin

Company policy has caused us to migrate from Source Gear - Vault to TFS 2010.  So here I am at my first check in and I notice I can only provide 1 single comment.

In vault my pending changes had a comments box which I could keep updated per file, so say I had ten files checked out.

File 1  - Comment A
File 2  - Comment B
File 3  - Comment C
...
..
File 10 - Comment J

Then I also could provide a general comment indicating what the change set for.

In TFS it appears that there is only 1 single comment box per change set?  Is there no way of entering comments per file as I go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot provide comments per file. Comments are always per Changeset, and thus for multiple files at once. Checking in files individually is not a good idea, since that will probably cause a lot of issues with Continuous Integration builds should you go towards build, test and deployment automation.

Generally you will associate a checkin with a task, you can describe in detail what you did or were planning to do as part of the task description.

Comment: I find this unfortunate.  I always have performed a changeset in vault.  I.e 10 files was one atomic check-in, but I had 11 comments.  1 Change set defining what was all changing, but then extra details per file

Comment: Sorry :S... But this is how it is... You could cobble something together using a custom checkin policy and a checkin-note containing an XML structure or a custom field on the task workitem. Not pretty, but it might work ;).